# Перенос непрерывной строки текста в блоке с фиксированной шириной

Tags: html, css, форматирование

Пример кода:

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Как видно текст вылез из блока потому что он непрерывный, нужно вписать его в DIV не увеличивая ширины блока (сделать перенос). Можно только увеличивать высоту блока. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap

Comment: @Visman спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Используйте знаки переноса `&shy;`:**

`&shy;` - разрывает слова при необходимости в тех местах, в которых вы укажете и добавляет знак переноса

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>xxx&shy;xxx&shy;xxx&shy;xxx&shy;xxx&shy;xxx</div>
```

**Используйте тег переноса слова `<wbr>`:**

`<wbr>`- тоже самое, но без знака переноса

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>xxx<wbr>xxx<wbr>xxx<wbr>xxx<wbr>xxx<wbr>xxx</div>
```

**Используйте свойство `word-wrap`:**

`word-wrap: break-word;` - разрывает слова без учета грамматики

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

**Используйте свойство `hyphens`:**

`hyphens` по идее должен автоматически определять где расставлять знаки переноса с учетом грамматики, но пока он слабо поддерживается браузерами.

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. довольно полное описание решения проблемы